# Adding tracking link to email from mail merge

Tags: c#, mailmerge

I am seeking advice about adding a tracking link to an email sent from Word as part of a mail merge.

Tools such as Google or ConstantContact add 1-pixel image which is rendered on the client. When we try to add the same in Word it renders the image "before" sending the email and hence we do not get tracking.

How can we accomplish the same through MS Word-based campaigns?